# Grails Security Plugin: Requestmap is not consistence with database

Tags: security, grails, plugins

I am new to Grails, and I would like to use requestMap for the security portion. However, if I update the rules in database, the new rules will not take effect till I restart the web application.

Does anyone has the same issue? or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

the request map is cached and you have to clear it after updating the database using `springSecurityService.clearCachedRequestmaps()`. This is shown in the plugins documentation in the [requestmap cache](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/single.html#requestmapInstances) section.

Comment: But I am using the default stuff, the document said if using the default, the plugin will handle all this for you, isn't it? Or I may mess up sth. Do you happen to know where can I check this? Another dump question, I am actually updating the rules via mySql but not through my web application, does it matter?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by default stuff. The above link to the docs says you have to clear the cache if you modify a request map entry. It does not matter how you change it (code or db), you have to clear the cache, otherwise there is no reason for spring security to reload the map.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this, I knew there is something wrong with the cache. However my RequestmapController is generated by the plugin, so where should I put this method? I believe the generated code did this already,right?